# Create subview on awakeFromNib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsview, nsimageview

I'm trying to create a `NSImageView` programmatically as a subview of another `NSImageView` when `awakeFromNib` is called.
My code is as follows (`Fader` is defined in `MyImageView.h`):

```
@implementation MyImageView

- (void)awakeFromNib {

Fader = [NSImageView initWithFrame: [self frame]];

}
```

I get the warning message `"NSImageView may not respong to +initWithFrame"`. When I build, the app simply frizzes without showing anything, and I have to `"force quit"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve forgotten to send `+alloc` in order to allocate the object. Change that line to:

```
Fader = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: [self frame]];
```

Comment: Yes, noticed it now too. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: Also important to note that "Fader" should be "fader" as it's a variable. Class names are capitalized but variables (including instance variables) should begin with lower-case letters by convention. Since the Wide World expects this convention, it makes your code harder to understand *at a glance* when sharing it with others. Conventions are there for universal understanding. :-)